# Running for loop function inside Laravel Observable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have an orders table with `orderStatus` and `paymentStatus` fields. When an order is made, the `orderStatus` is set to `initialized` and `paymentStatus` set to `pending`.

At the point when the order is created, I want to check if `paymentStatus` changed. If it did not, change after 12 minutes I want to update `orderStatus` to `completed` and 'paymentStatus`to`aborted`.

I have a schedule task that checks every one minute but unfortunately I have not been able to run cron jobs on Bluehost. So I tried using a for loop in the `create` method of `OrderObserver` but the code doesn't work.

```
public function created(Order $order)
{
    // check if user reservation record exist
    $reservation = Reservation::where([
        ['user_id', $order->user_id],
        ['product_id', $order->product_id]
    ]);

    if ($reservation) {

        // delete reservation record
        $reservation->delete();
    }

    // start 12 mins count down for payment
    $period = ($order->created_at)->diffInMinutes();

    for ($counter = 0; $period >= 12; ++$counter) {
        $order->update([
            'orderStatus'   => 'completed',
            'paymentStatus' => 'aborted'
        ]);
    }
}
```

From php artisan tinker, I can see that this part of the code works

```
for ($counter = 0; $period >= 12; ++$counter) {
    $order->update([
        'orderStatus'   => 'completed',
        'paymentStatus' => 'aborted'
    ]);
}
```

Why does the code not run in the observable?

Comment: What do you mean by "the code doesn't work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, the order record doesn't get updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have to do something with the fact that you are blocking php executing for 12 minutes, by making it be stuck in the same for loop. You're probably exceeding the [max executing time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

> max_execution_time integer
>
> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

Seeing as artisan tinker runs from the command line, it makes sense that it works there.

Comment: Will setting it to 720 fix it?

Comment: It should be slightly more than 12 minutes, as the script itself will need time to run as well. Having said so, it is very bad practice to keep a script running for as long as 12 minutes. The default of 30 seconds is very sensible and you should avoid increasing this without proper knowledge. Your motivation for doing so is that Bluejob does not support cronjobs, but [this page](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/411) claims otherwise. I would advice you to look into that first.

Comment: What I said is that I have not been able to run the cron job and have raised a ticket with them for over 48hrs now and its still unresolved. That's the reason why I am searching for an alternative way to do this.

Comment: In that case, as a temporary solution, you could create a controller which updates the `orderStatus`. Then call the url for that controller every minute from another website like https://cron-job.org/. Doing so will not result in php having to wait for 12 minutes.

Comment: Hmm that might work. Let me have a look at that solution

Comment: Yo dude, you just saved me all the lost time I spent trying to run the cron job on Bluehost. One question though, how reliable is cron-job.org for production environment?

Comment: Sorry I wouldn't know if it's reliable, you could check reviews for that. I'd use it as a temporary workaround till Bluehost gets their stuff in order though

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I intend doing.